# c++, output of FindFirstFile()

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote the program of finding file using `FindFirstFile(...)` function. But when I try to print the output of this function, there is a several strings of unknown characters printed in console windows.
I read some posts, there was written to try using `wcout` instead of `cout`. I try it, but it doesn't help. I think, that the problem is in difference between ANSI and UNICODE encodings. Can somebody help me? I will be very thankful for any help!

Here is my code:

```
#include "FindFile.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FindFileCl::Execute(Input * input, Response * response )
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;

    HANDLE h = FindFirstFileA((input->FileName).c_str(),    // name of the file

        &FindFileData);
    if (h)
    {   



        cout << "Search Results:\n";

        cout<<(FindFileData.cFileName);


        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "File is NOT found:" << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }




}
```

Comment: Try using `FindFirstFile` and not `FindFirstFileA`, and build your program in Unicode. Use `chcp 65001` in console to change codepage to UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Nemanja Boric. I tried to use FindFirstFile instead of FindFirstFileA, but then it causes problems with first parameter of the function, so I use FindFirstFileA.

Comment: Oh, you need to use `WIN32_FIND_DATA` instead of `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`.

Comment: I tried it also, but there is another problem. But I received an answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, not `NULL`:

> If the function fails or fails to locate files from the search string in the `lpFileName` parameter, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and the contents of `lpFindFileData` are indeterminate. To get extended error information, call the `GetLastError` function.

and `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is `#define`d as `-1` (following macro located in *WinBase.h*):

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)
```

Meaning the `if (h)` will be entered in either success or failure. In the event of failure, `cFileName` will not be modified resulting in junk being printed as it is not initialized. Change the `if` condition to explicitly check for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`:

```
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, hmjd! I did as you said, and the strange characters doesn't printed! Everything is working! You helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of the "least bad" ways would be to convert the Unicode name to the Console's encoding.

For this, I suggest compiling in Unicode (There's a project option for that in Visual Studio >=8; otherwise you have to define both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` manually), using the TCHAR version of FindFirstFile(), and then using CharToOem() or [CharToOemBuff()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (neither is perfect). -- Or alternately, use the W version followed by WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP).

Comment: Thank you for answer, Medinoc. hmjd also answered my question, I did as he said, and my program works. Howewer, thank you very much for your answer!